# Efficient way to light up/cast shadows on a voxel terrain

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shadow, light

I'm using a BufferGeometry and some predefined data to create an object similar to a Minecraft chunk (made of voxels and containing cave-like structures). I'm having a problem lighting up this object efficently.

At the moment I'm using a `MeshLambertMaterial` and a `DirectionalLight` which enables me to cast shadows on voxels not in view of the light, however this isn't efficient to use for a large terrain because it requires a very large shadow map and will often cause glitchy shadow artifacts as a result.

Here's the code I'm using to add the indices and vertices to the BufferGeometry:

```
// Add indices to BufferGeometry
for ( var i = 0; i < section.indices.length; i ++ ) {
    var j = i * 3;
    var q = section.indices[i];

    indices[ j ]     = q[0] % chunkSize;
    indices[ j + 1 ] = q[1] % chunkSize;
    indices[ j + 2 ] = q[2] % chunkSize;
}

// Add vertices to BufferGeometry
for ( var i = 0; i < section.vertices.length; i ++ ) {
    var q = section.vertices[i];

    // There's 1 color for every 4 vertices (square)
    var hexColor = section.colors[i / 4];

    addVertex( i, q[0], q[1], q[2], hexColor );
}
```

**And my 'chunk' example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9sSyz/4/

**A screenshot:** [image]

If I were to remove the shadows from my example, all voxels on the correct side would be lit up even if another voxel obstructed the light. I just need another scalable way to give the illusion of a shadow. Perhaps by changing vertex colors if not in view of the light? It doesn't have to be as accurate as the current shadow implementation so changing the vertex colors (to give a blocky vertex-bound shadow) would be enough.

Would appreciate any help or advice. Thanks.

Comment: (1) You have the light at the camera location. Offset it. http://jsfiddle.net/9sSyz/1/ (2) I would suggest ambient occlusion post-processing and no shadow map. What exactly it is that you currently do not like -- visually, that is?

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some research on ambient occlusion. It's not that I don't like how it looks. Just having performance issues using the same method on multiple of these 'chunks' due to the size of the shadow map needed, so thought I'd ask if there's a better (even less visually impressive) way to make the caves, etc dark. :)

Comment: (1) Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/9sSyz/5/. I removed the shadowmap and added ambient occlusion. toggle ao with t-key. (2) Also, as an experiment, I replaced lambert with basic material. http://jsfiddle.net/9sSyz/6/. The ao effect is incredible.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've been experimenting with your basic material example and I've added FXAA (disabled the built in one) and it's looking pretty awesome! http://jsfiddle.net/9sSyz/7/ I think I'm going to keep it like this and find another way to add shadows. I don't think something as basic as this warrants using MeshLambertMaterial with dynamic shadows. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hmmm, personally, I prefer no-shadows + MeshLambert + ao over MeshBasic + ao. But... to each his own. :-)

Comment: Problem I have with using MeshLambert + no-shadows is that it doesn't stop light passing through objects, so holes/caves not open to the light won't be dark. I was thinking about using MeshBasic and just going through the array used to build the geometry and changing the color of any voxels in a closed space so it gives the illusion of darkness. Wouldn't be nowhere near as accurate as ThreeJS's shadows but it should do. That sound like a good idea? Can't really think of another way unless I use shadows. :)

Comment: That does sound like a good idea. It would be great if you would be willing to show a toggle-able example of the MeshBasic + ao + vertex shading approach.

Comment: Will do! :) I'll post a link here when I've got it working. Besides that, any idea why SSAO is causing these weird lines? http://puu.sh/6OSR8.jpg I noticed on your JSFiddle you commented on how near and far needs to be tight. Would you know how I would increase the distance and avoid these lines? (near=1 and far=500 in that image) I'm a newbie at the whole WebGL shaders thing so sorry for the constant questions. Perhaps I should post on the ThreeJS forums instead?

Comment: I think you will just have to experiment... and share your conclusions, if you are willing.  Also, please know that the three.js github site is not a help site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you have large terrains, the idea is to split the scene into more *cascades* and each cascade has its own shadow map. Technique is called *CSM - cascaded shadow maps*. Problem is, I haven't heard of an webGL example that implements this technique. CSMs are used on dynamic scenes. But I'm not sure how easy would be to implement this with Three.js.

Second option is adding ambient occlusion, as suggested by WestLagnley, but it's just an occlusion, not a shadow. Results are very different.

Third option, if your scene is mostly static - baked shadows. So, preprocessed textures that you simply apply to the terrain etc. To support dynamic objects, just render their shadow maps and apply those to some geometry that just mimics shadowed area (perhaps, a plane that hovers slightly above ground and receives the shadow etc).

Any combination of the techniques mentioned is also an option.

P.S. Could you also supply a screenshot, fiddles fail to load.

Comment: Cascaded shadow maps are supported by three.js and an example can be found here: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2_control.html. three.js.r.65

Comment: Thanks Abstract Algorithm! @WestLangley Would you happen to know why cascading shadows doesn't work with my BufferGeometry? Getting the error "array size must be a positive integer" for the shaders var 'MAX_SHADOWS', but not adding the BufferGeometry to the scene removes these errors. http://jsfiddle.net/9sSyz/3/

Comment: Also Abstract Algorithm, here's a screenshot of the fiddle: http://puu.sh/6NbeC.png Nothing wrong with it visually, just wanted a way for make the shadows more efficient. :)

Comment: Need more efficient shadow - CSM is the way to go. Please accept the answer, and if you have further problems, ask a new question on the forum.